# Sparql Query results in Tamil using Eclipse

Tags: java, sparql, protege, tamil

We are trying to execute SparQL query for our OWL Ontology created in Tamil using Protege in Eclipse IDE. The code works fine but the results don't seem to appear in Tamil. The following is the code and the output.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.OWL;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;

import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaOWLModel;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.OWLModel;


public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,           NullPointerException {

try
{
    //opening owl file
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new  File("C:/Users/Sandhya/Desktop/Ontology/newtamil.owl"));
    Model model=ModelFactory.createMemModelMaker().createDefaultModel() ;
    model.read(in,null);       
  System.out.println(model);
   in.close();
   String queryString =
         "PREFIX pizza:   <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2013/3/newtamil.owl#> "+     

   " PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+
     "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "+
     "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "+
     "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
     "SELECT ?subject ?object "+
     "  WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object }";
    com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query q = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model);
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
    while (results.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(results.getResourceModel() );

    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, q);
    qe.close();
    }
   }catch(java.lang.NullPointerException e){ System.out.println(e);}
    catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Query Failed !");
    }

   }

   }
```

Output:
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## | subject                                                                                                                     | object                                                                                                    |

|%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%80%E0%AE%BE%E0%AF%82                   | %E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%AA |

### |%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%82%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AA | %E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%AA |

We want this to be displayed in Tamil. We also installed unicode and redirected the output into a text file and checked but it still does not give the expected result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jena prints in UTF-8.

It looks like the data is already %-encoded.